# Angular 2: clear textarea from component class

Tags: angular

I have a textarea with an option list.
If one of the options is clicked and if enter key is pressed inside the text area the tag should be sent to the server and the text area should be cleared.

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag.tag}}</li>
<li><textarea #box (keyup)="searchTag(box.value)" (key.enter)="addTag(box.value)"></textarea>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let tag of options" (click)="addTag(tag.tag)">{{tag.tag}}</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How could I clear the text area, before or after information is sent to server? The clear command should call from the addTag function.

Comment: box.value = null in addTag function

Comment: I already try this, box is not known inside the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind default value to textarea

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="defaultValue"></textarea>
```

The component code:

```
export class TaggingComponent {
    defaultValue: string = '';

    addTag(value) {
      this.defaultValue = ''; 
    }
}
```

Be sure `FormsModule` has been imported to `app.module.ts`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    FormsModule
    ...
   ],
```

Comment: I tested it several times, but I did not get it work this way. 
The side is not loading anymore and firefox returns error message: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'

Comment: Can you show your component and html template code?

Comment: Check your app.module.ts file. You should import FormsModule. The answer is updated with details.

Comment: Welcome. If the answer is right then mark it as the best ))